# Accessing values of a data.frame depending on factors

Tags: r, dataframe

Starting with a data.frame like this

```
df<-NULL
Time<-c(1,1,1,2,2,3)
Fac<-c("a","b","c","a","b","c")
Val<-c(1,4,6,7,8,43)
df<-data.frame(Time,Fac,Val)

Time   Fac  Val
1      a    2
1      b    4
1      c    6
2      a    7
2      b    8
3      c    43
```

I want to normalize every value of "Val" in dependence of the factors in "Fac".

E.g. for the factor a: I want to divide every value in "Val" with the factor "a" trough 2. For the factor "b" every value in "Val" with the factor "b" trough 4.

I tried doing it with

```
by(df,df$Fac,FUN=function(x)x["Val"]/x[["Val"]][1])
```

This creates list of the factors with the normalized values. But that leads to the problem how to combine the lists again, because the factors can be irregularly (eg. a,b,c,a,b,a,b,c,c,a,b) and the corresponding factors in the "Time" column have to be preserved as well.

I hope my problem is clear and i would appreciate every help.

Comment: You can combine your original data with an object that contains denominator information (this will add another column), after this you just need to divide columns: `merge(df, data.frame(Fac = c("a", "b", "c"), denom = c(2, 4, 1)))`

Comment: What do you mean normalize? Is each value from a group always divided by the minimum value of that group?

Comment: @PoGibas that works aswell, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution using `dplyr`. I assume you are normalizing by dividing the first value from each group. If you are normalizing by dividing the minimum value from each group, change `first(Val)` to `min(Val)`.

```
library(dplyr)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  group_by(Fac) %>%
  mutate(Val = Val/first(Val)) %>%
  ungroup()
dat2
# # A tibble: 6 x 3
#    Time Fac     Val
#   <dbl> <fct> <dbl>
# 1     1 a      1   
# 2     1 b      1   
# 3     1 c      1   
# 4     2 a      7   
# 5     2 b      2   
# 6     3 c      7.17
```

**Coding Style Advice:**

`df<-NULL` is not necessary, we can ignore that. Also, `df` is a function name in R, so it is better to use another name.

Example data creation:

```
Time<- c(1,1,1,2,2,3)
Fac <- c("a","b","c","a","b","c")
Val <- c(1,4,6,7,8,43)
dat <- data.frame(Time,Fac,Val)
```